# apt broken - Unable to Install or Update packages as pending removal keeps failing

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dpkg

I have a problem with an old SQL Server package on my Kubuntu install which I installed from the old repository by accident (missed a line when commenting out stuff for a new build).

This has left me in an infuriating situation where I still have `msodbcsql17` installed. I have tried to remove it but it failed and now everything is stuck.

The PPA that it was installed from had been removed (as it was the wrong version and there isn't one for 22.04 yet).

I have since re-added the PPA hoping I could reinstall it but that won't work either now.

I have tried the following...

`sudo apt install --reinstall msodbcsql17` - Reinstallation of msodbcsql17 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.

These had the same result...

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-all msodbcsql17`

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq msodbcsql17`

`sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --purge msodbcsql17`

```
(Reading database ... 500760 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing msodbcsql17 (17.9.1.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--remove):
 installed msodbcsql17 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
```

I have also tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before all of the above but that won't work due to another dependency issue that I need to install for `dropbox` which I seem unable to fix because of the issue with `msodbcsql17`.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dropbox:
 dropbox depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.36.3); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package dropbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dropbox
```

Where can I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this after finding an odd comment somewhere else.

In order to unlock the fixes I had to manually move some files. In my case, with the package above I did the following...

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
ls msodbc*
```

This showed me that there were files for my package there.

```
mkdir .recoverey
mv msodbc* .recovery/
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Getting the files out of the way seems to be key - Once they were moved out `apt` was then able to fix itself and the other packages all fixed themselves up too.